# Custom 404 not displaying

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have a webforms project that I've made a custom 404 page for.

I've written my redirect in my web.config but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the code

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

When I visit `localhost:(port number)/about` I'm taken to the about page. When I visit the same thing but spell 'about' incorrectly, I'm taken to the default 404 page

[image: default 404]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom errors handles aspx pages. You can remove/comment your `customErrors` section and use `httpErrors` like this instead:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="404.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Reference: [HTTP Errors](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors)